# Using composer without framework

Tags: php

I have php script which is very simple, so I don't use any framework like `symfony`

My folder structure is here below

```
myapp
  -vendor
  -composer.jspn
  -script
    -myapp.php
```

So I want to use library in myapp.php

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
$spreadSheet = new Spreadsheet;
```

It says `Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found`

What is the best practice for this case??

Comment: You need to include the `vendor/autoload.php` file created by composer. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: It solves my problem simply. thank you very much